# SQL Server 2012 query returns different date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to select a specific time schedule of a certain date which is 10-04-2018 but it returns a value of 10-03-2018.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_schedule
WHERE [Date] = '10-04-2018'
    AND [StartTime] BETWEEN '8:01'
        AND '9:59'
    OR [EndTime] BETWEEN '8:01'
        AND '9:59';
```

[image]

Comment: What are you storing date and time separately?  This is bad table design IMO.  Consider storing everything as a single datetime.

Comment: Do you mean I should normalize it?

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure it's because of your OR clause.

```
OR [EndTime] BETWEEN '8:01'
        AND '9:59';
```

It might be easier to understand how your query works if you add some parenthesis:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_schedule
WHERE ( [Date] = '10-04-2018'
        AND [StartTime] BETWEEN '8:01'
        AND '9:59' )
    OR 
    ( [EndTime] BETWEEN '8:01'
        AND '9:59' ) ;
```

This happens by default because of how operator precedence is set up. You can find more information about it, [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

But, in short, AND has a higher operator precedence than OR, which is why it will be evaluated first, putting together your first two conditions `[Date] = & [StartTime] BETWEEN`, then the OR will be applied on this result combined with the `[EndTime] BETWEEN` condition.

I recommend using parenthesis when using OR and I think the query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_schedule
WHERE [Date] = '10-04-2018'
      AND 
      (  [StartTime] BETWEEN '8:01' AND '9:59' 
      OR [EndTime] BETWEEN '8:01' AND '9:59' ) ;
```

Comment: @Kcird And notice how much more **readable** (and therefore understandable) it is with a simple format improvement - moving the upper bound for the between conditions to the same line as the lower bound.

Answer (score 3):

You should use  "(" after AND in case you need the date on this day only:

```
    SELECT *
FROM tbl_schedule
WHERE [Date] = '10-04-2018'
    AND ( [StartTime] BETWEEN '8:01'
        AND '9:59'
    OR [EndTime] BETWEEN '8:01'
        AND '9:59')
```